# Bucket Sort JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, search, bucket-sort

I am having trouble implementing a search engine for my webpage in JavaScript. Firstly, I have an array[strings] of classnames. With the classnames I want to do a bucketsort with buckets namely a-z, so a bucketSize[a-z]. Once I detect the first letter of the classname[i] I place it in the correct bucket. That is my first function classSort().

Then next I want to be able to read an input from HTML  tag and search the buckets with the first letter and return it. I am having trouble creating a for loop that run through the bucket and return every string with the letter that the user typed. I am still fairly new to programming and im trying to challenge by self to built a website, but i keep getting stuck on the searching of the webpage. This is my code so far.

```
let classNames;
let bucketSize;


function classSort(classNames, bucketSize){

 //empty check
if(classNames.length === 0){
    return classNames;
}

//initialize buckets
var bucketSize = new Array();

for (var aToz = 'a'; aToz <= 'z'; aToz++){
    bucketSize.push(new Array());
}

//Detect first letter of each ith String and put it in the right bucket
for ( var i = 0; i <= classNames.length; i++){

    for (var aToz = 'a'; aToz <= 'z'; aToz++){
        if (className[i].startsWith(String.valueOf(aToz)){
            bucketSize.find(aToz).push(classNames[i]);
        }
    }
}

function classSearch(inputSearch){

document.getElementById("submit").onsubmit = function()

inputSearch = document.getElementById("search").value;

if (inputSearch === ""){
    return ("Nothing was typed!")
}else{
for (var aToz = 'a'; aToz <= 'z'; aToz++){
    if (inputSearch.startsWith(String.valueOf(aToz)){
        //for (var i = 0; i <= )
        bucketSize.find(aToz).pop(classNames[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated. THANKS!!!!

Comment: You can’t increment characters in JavaScript. `var c = 'a'; c++` results in `c` being `NaN`. `function()` is missing an opening brace. `Array#find` doesn’t work like that. `Array#pop` doesn’t work like that. `inputSearch = ""` isn’t a comparison. `for (var i =0; i <= )` isn’t complete. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: no this is a personal project in which were are working on a tutoring app that I am doing with my computer engineering class

Comment: how would I create an array for 26 buckets and be able to distingush the buckets and add the classname in the correct bucket

Comment: Your code is a decent start, but does have some pretty serious issues, as @Ry- mentioned, that make it difficult to answer the question as is, including things like missing brackets. I would suggest first going over your code with a classmate or TA who is more proficient in JavaScript, so that you can explore each line together in person and put together something closer to what you're intending.